# Legendre transformation of a functional

Tags: calculus-of-variations, quantum-field-theory, frechet-derivative, functional-calculus

Consider a functional $F[f]$ where $f=f(x)$. What is the definition of its Legendre transform?

I know about the Legendre transforma of functions. For example, $f=f(x)$ will have the Legendre transform $$g(m)=f-mx\tag{1}$$ where $m=\frac{df}{dx}$. By the same analogy, the Legendre transform of the functional $S[f]$ can be writeen as $$G[\frac{\delta F}{\delta f(x)}]=F[f]-\frac{\delta F}{\delta f(x)}f(x).\tag{2}$$

1. Is Eq. (2) correct generalization of Legendre transform for functionals?
2. If yes, how can we simplify (2) to express the second term as an integral over $x$? I know that $$\frac{\delta F[f]}{\delta f(y)}=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{F[f(x)+\epsilon\delta(x-y)]-F[f]}{\epsilon}.$$ But I can't understand how to proceed next.

**Context** I'm trying to define the effective action functional $\Gamma[\phi_{c}]=W[J]-\int d^4x J(x)\phi_{c}(x)$ where the symbols have their usual meaning in Quantum Field Theory.

Comment: The Legendre transform is defined in the generality of locally convex spaces in the book 'Convexity' by Barry Simon. From your definition of the functional derivative, it seems that $F$ acts in the space of distributions, so that might be the appropriate setting for you. In order for someone to provide you with a more useful answer, you probably need to be somewhat more specific concerning the generality that you are interested in.

Comment: @JonasDahlbæk This definition of functional derivatives are used by physicists. For example, it is given in the book Geometry, Topology and Physics by M. Nakahara. And also in Lewis Ryder's Quantum field theory book page 173, Eq. 5.55

Comment: There should be an integral:
$$G[g]=F[f]- \int g(x) \, f(x) \, dx,$$
where $g(x) = \frac{\delta F}{\delta f(x)}.$

Comment: @md2perpe Used (1) to write (2) by analogy. Is that wrong? Why would the integral appear?

Comment: In multiple dimensions there's a summation over the coordinate index. For functionals, $x$ corresponds to this index, and we should therefore "sum" over it.

Comment: The formula
$$\frac{\delta F[f]}{\delta f(y)} = \lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{F[f(x)+\epsilon\delta(x-y)]-F[f]}{\epsilon}$$
for functional derivative is common among physicists but is not mathematically correct. The functional $F$ takes a function, but $f(x) + \epsilon \delta(x-y)$ is not a function; it's a distribution. A better formula is
$$\langle \delta F[f], \phi \rangle = \left. \frac{d}{d\lambda} F[f+\lambda\phi] \right|_{\lambda=0}$$

Answer (score 4):

In one dimension we have $f^*(p) = f(x) - p x,$ where $x = (f')^{-1}(p).$

In several dimensions we have $f^*(p) = f(x) - p \cdot x,$ where $x = (\nabla f)^{-1}(p).$

In continuous dimensions we then should have $f^*(p) = f(x) - \langle p, x \rangle,$ where $x = (\delta f)^{-1}(p)$ with $\delta f$ being the functional derivative of $f.$

In other notation:
$$F^*[g] = F[f]- \int g(x) \, f(x) \, dx,$$
where $f(x) = \left(\frac{\delta F}{\delta f(x)}\right)^{-1}[g].$